# Background not showing

Tags: css

I have a background image set on a web page with the following CSS:

```
    body, html
    {
        background-image: url(Content/Images/bg-lounge-2-l.jpg);
        background-repeat: repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed; /*background-position: 0 -390px;*/
    }
```

This background was visible until late last night, in Firefox and IE, but at some point something changed and it no longer shows in the browsers.  It does show in the VS 2008 designer, and the image is in the correct location.  If I paste the image url into my address bar, I can view the image.  What could be wrong?

Comment: typical problem is caching. also, never seen anyone apply styling to 'html' before :)

Comment: I added it as a desperate measure last night, saw it recommended for some reason somewhere and I was at wit's end. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the url to the image is relative to the path to the CSS file, and not the HTML file that loads the CSS file. Also check that you have the correct spelling and capitalization.